# Why does 4-bit mux test bench code give x?

Tags: verilog, mux, test-bench

I can't put my finger on why is it not working.  I ran a simulation on `edaplayground`, and I get an "x" in the output every time the select changes to 0. I properly get "1" when sel is "1" though.

The code:

```
 module mux8_2(input [3:0]a,[3:0]b,sel,output [3:0]out);   
 assign out=(sel)?a:b;  
 endmodule
```

and the testbench:

```
 module mux8_2_tb; 

 reg [3:0]A;  

 reg [3:0]B;  

 reg SEL;  

 wire [3:0]OUT;  

 mux8_2 UUT(A,B,SEL,OUT);  

 initial  
  begin  

 $dumpfile("dump.vcd");  

 $dumpvars(1);  

 A=4'b1; B=4'b0; SEL=1'b1;

 #1 SEL=1'b0;  
 #1 SEL=1'b1;  
 #1 SEL=1'b0;  
 #1 SEL=1'b1;  
 #1 SEL=1'b0;  
 #1 SEL=1'b1;  
 #1;
 end

 endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your results; the `OUT` signal is always known for me.

But, I do get a compile warning:

```
The following 1-bit expression is connected to 4-bit port "sel" of module 
  "mux8_2", instance "UUT"
```

This can be fixed:

```
module mux8_2(input [3:0]a,[3:0]b, input sel,output [3:0]out);
```

In your code `sel` inherited the width from the previous signal (`[3:0]b`).  Your code is equivalent to:

```
module mux8_2(input [3:0]a,[3:0]b,[3:0]sel,output [3:0]out);
```

Adding another `input` keyword before `sel` forces it to use the default width of 1 bit.